# How many ways can you choose 4 non empty subsets from q 10 element set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways can you divide the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ into a 4 non empty subsets?

Hint: there's a formula states that the number of all the functions from $A \to \{1,2,3,4\}$
that are surjective is: 818,250

I wondered if there's an easy way of calculating this? Every time I see I need to make ugly calculations without the use of the hint. 
Someone knows how to use it or solving this properly?

Thanks.

Comment: The standard method for counting the functions is Inclusion/Exclusion. Else look at Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: There is a transposition in your post, the number of functions is $818520$. Dividing this by $4!$ gives the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the 4 sets necessarily disjoint? If so, the answer is just 818,250, by considering each surjective map's pre-image. It should be straightforward enough to see that there's a 1-1 correspondence between these pre-images and choices of 4 non-empty disjoint subsets.

Then just divide by 4! and you're good. :)

Comment: Counting functions overcounts, it counts the number of ways to put the objects into *labelled* boxes, at least one in each box.

Comment: The number of functions given by OP is slightly off, it should be $818520$.